# Use database dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

This execution is giving me the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 
    Incorrect syntax near 'go'. 
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 
    'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

If i remove the "GO" it gives me just the second one.

Any hints of what am I missing?

```
declare @dbname varchar(500)
set @dbname='master'
Exec ('

Use ' + @dbname + '

go

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[krijo_database] @dbname nvarchar(2000), @Direktoria varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @stringu nvarchar(100)
    set @stringu = 
    ''CREATE DATABASE '' + @dbname 
    exec (@stringu)
End
')
```

Answer

```
declare @dbname varchar(500)
set @dbname='kontabel'

Exec(
'Use ' + @dbname +'

Exec (''
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[krijo_database] @dbname nvarchar(2000), @Direktoria varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @stringu nvarchar(100)
    set @stringu = 
    ''''create DATABASE '''' + @dbname 
    exec (@stringu)
End
'')

')
```

Actually I tried like this and it worked but I had to change quotes.
The real procedure that I would like to use is more than 50000 lines and I can't go and manually change the quotes to everything.

Is there a better way?

Comment: "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'go'.
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. "
If i remove the "GO" it gives me just the second one.

Comment: I do this all the time, it's perfectly fine... writing answer...

Comment: Did you solve this? If you did, who's answer helped you the most?

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. Using "GO" is incorrect... there is no SQL keyword called "GO"... **that's just a hack that SQL Server Management Studio is performing for you.**
2. You need to the CREATE PROCEDURE command in it's own context... simple.

Here's the slight modification to your script:

```
declare @dbname varchar(500)
set @dbname='master'
Exec ('

Use ' + @dbname + '

EXECUTE(''create PROCEDURE [dbo].[krijo_database] @dbname nvarchar(2000), @Direktoria varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @stringu nvarchar(100)
    set @stringu = 
    ''''CREATE DATABASE '''' + @dbname 
    exec (@stringu)
End'')
')
```

So the answer is to put another "EXECUTE" command **inside** the first EXECUTE command. I do this all the time, a lot of times in an "sp_msforeachdb". You can nest those bad boys as long as you want.

Comment: Thanks i think i already posted this answear. The thing is that i while doing that i had to change some quotes and a can't aford that in a procedure which have more than 50000 lines!
My point is that i want to create a procedue to a just created database at the same time!

Comment: Firstly, you can declare a VARCHAR(MAX) field... so there is no 8000 character limit as someone has said. Secondly, you can do a "FIND-AND-REPLACE"... highlight the code, press CONTROL+H, replace "'" with "''" (replace single quotes with two single quotes).

Comment: thanks i tried that as well but it seems that varchar(max) doesn't countain more than 800 charachters

Comment: VARCHAR(MAX) allows 2 gigabytes of data... that's a lot more than 800 :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I had code which was updating database structure based on scripts.
I end up with split file by 'go' and execute separately each fragment. Can you try this?

So, first exec use statement, and than exec createprocedure.

Be sure to verify that it is created in proper database

Comment: I thinks i tried that and it wasn't executing the use Exec statement!
please post and example just to verify if i didn't do any syntax errors!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I didn't notice something.

maybe it's the Exec inside the Exec that's causing the error?

or because your'e assigning a nvarchar(2000) to a nvarchar(100)

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near 'go'. Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. " If i remove the "GO" it gives me just the second one.

try this without any `use` or `go`: `create PROCEDURE '+@dbname+'.[dbo].[krijo_database] @dbname nvarchar(2000)`

Comment: Well i already did it before posting to this forum and it gave me an error saying that it could not be done

Comment: declare @dbname varchar(500)
set @dbname='kontabel'

Exec(
'Use ' + @dbname +'

Exec (''
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[krijo_database] @dbname nvarchar(2000), @Direktoria varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
 declare @stringu nvarchar(100)
 set @stringu = 
 ''''create DATABASE '''' + @dbname 
 exec (@stringu)
End
'')

')

Actually i tried like this and it worked but i i had to change quotes.
The Real procedure that i would like to use it is a very big one, more dhan 50000 lines and i can't go on an changing the quotes to everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GO like that

1. It isn't a SQL command
2. It tells SSMS to split the batch

If you remove it, then you'll get "first in batch" error which is expected

In this case, why not just do this...

```
Use master
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[krijo_database] @dbname nvarchar(2000), @Direktoria varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @stringu nvarchar(100)
    set @stringu = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbname 
    exec (@stringu)
End
GO
```

Why do need dynamic SQL to create a stored procedure?

Comment: i need to create this procedure in another database!

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.create_database @name nvarchar(100)
AS
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(100)
    SET @sql = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@name)
    EXEC (@sql) 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Real procedure that i would like to use it is a very big one, more dhan 50000 lines and i can't go on an changing the quotes to everything

Microsoft SQL Server has a maximum length of varchar of 8000 characters.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3788256/Data-Types-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm

Comment: that is why i'm using Exec directly!
And it created me the procedure but not on the databse that i wanted!
That is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

What you're after can't be done I don't think.

See [this article](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/how-not-to-use-use.aspx) for reference

Answer (score 0):

you should create stored procedure with that portion with variable.

Answer (score 0):

I used SQl DMO!
Great feature both for 32 and 64 bit,compatible with both SQL express and server!